# Get all occurrences of a similar string (which follows a pattern) within a text

Tags: regex, foreach, str-replace, preg-match-all

I've got a huge text which contains strings following the pattern:

{text1}
{text2}
...
{text10}

"text" will remain the same but the number which comes after will always be incremented. I can't predict its maximum.

Until today I've used this:

```
preg_match_all("{text.}", $content, $occurrences);
foreach ($occurrences[0] as $occurrence){
    $content = str_replace("{" . $occurrence . "}", "test", $content);
}
```

Everything worked fine until today when I've noticed that the preg_match_all rule doesn't work if I've got to replace multiple digits. This means basically it will detect "text2" but it won't detect "text10".

How should I alter this preg_match rule to detect any number after "text"?

Thanks,
Bogdan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all("{text\d+}", $content, $occurrences);
```

or

```
preg_match_all("{text.+}", $content, $occurrences);
```

Try this. `.` matches only one character. That is why `text2` is matched but not `text10` as there are 2 characters after `text`.